# Table Fill can't fill Row with Buttons

Tags: android, button, fill, android-tablelayout

I am trying to fill the first row of my table with only one button.. and the second row divided with two buttons, but I can't do it..
It appears always like this:

[image]

I already add the lines:
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"

Any clue why? This is how my XML is at the moment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:shrinkColumns="*" >

    <!-- 1 column -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Column 2" />
    </TableRow>

    <!-- 2 columns -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:text="Column 3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:text="Column 4" />
    </TableRow>





</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add android:layout_span="2" to your first Button:

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_span="2"    
     android:text="Column 2" />
```